# See when branch was initially or last merged with github?

Tags: github

Im working with Github and a forked version of a repo. Ive found an issue in a branch with testing and I need to know when this first occurred.

Looking at the original repo, how can I find out when the branch was first branched off, or when it was last merged? As our other testing would have caught this I know that it must not be in the previous release, so I don't need to look back any further than that. The problem I'm facing is I don't know when this was.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Releases are probably done by tags. Use [`git bisect`](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Debugging-with-Git#Binary-Search) to find the errorenous commit:

```
$ git bisect start
$ git bisect bad
$ git bisect v1.3.1   # <-- latest tag/commit that was working fine
# ... test the project
$ git bisect bad  # in case the error still occured
$ git bisect good # in case this commit was working fine
# ... continue the above step
```

This will give you the exact commit that introduced the error.